# Why does Visual Studio 2010 rebuild slower when not connected to the Internet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, html-agility-pack, nuget

At first I thought I was crazy, but since my internet has been cutting out fairly often, I am able to tell whenever it does by the fact that VS10 takes longer to rebuild my project whenever I lose connection to the internet. None of my other applications, besides my browsers, for obvious reasons, seem to suffer.

To test this yourself, just `ipconfig /release` and try to *rebuild restart debugging* your project after you've changed some line of code, and then `ipconfig /renew` and make a change and *rebuild and restart* debugging it again.

I'm using XNA, if that's relevant. My code does not explicitly try to connect to the web, as far as I can tell, unless `nuget` and `HTMLAgilityPack` need to connect to the web on rebuild.

edit: changed to restarting the debugger after a rebuild, not just a rebuild. I can only reproduce this on a fresh `XNA Windows Game` project, not a C# Console Application. Adding `HTMLAgilityPack` doesn't seem to have any effect on a project's startup time

Comment: You could use WireShark to monitor the traffic to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: (To the tune of Zoolander) The files are _in_ the cloud.

Comment: Well, I've tried it multiple times already and it never happened to me... Tried with 2008, 2010 and 2012... Note I'm using VS for web development. Maybe there's something specific to your project? Or does this happen to EVERY project of yours, even new ones?

Comment: If you find wireshark daunting, use Fiddler. In my case during build the SchemaResolver goes out and tries to resolve stuff on a non-existing site, for every XSD I have...

Comment: @walther I made an edit, it only happens so far with XNA builds. Make sure you're both rebuilding and restarting the debugger. The rebuild time is not affected, it was starting the debugger up afterwards.

Comment: Bet there's a cert its trying to validate against the root.  Just had a similar question recently.  No resolution that I can remember.

Comment: Going on with what Will mentioned, sometimes there are weird microsoft certs being loaded. While this isn't related to building, I did run into assembly loading taking a long time on a machine without internet access due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293639/windows-service-locks-up-on-assembly-load, so keep an eye out for that train of thought

Comment: @devshorts Thanks, I'll have to try this out.

Comment: Run TcpView from Sysinternals while you build, it will show any connection attempts made by Visual Studio. That should help isolate the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Code signing trying to find Verisign's (et. al.) servers?